# Problemas con ''Must declare the scalar variable'' SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, geojson

Estoy trabajando en un GeoJSON en SQL Server y tengo el problema que al querer usar OPENJSON me salta el error de ''Must declare the scalar variable'', entonces probé buscando ejemplos de la página https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/parsing-geojson-format-in-sql-server-2016/ba-p/384459

Este seria el ejemplo:

```
declare @polygon nvarchar(max) =
    N'{ "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [[35, 10], [45, 45], [15, 40], [10, 20], [35, 10]],
            [[20, 30], [35, 35], [30, 20], [20, 30]]
           ]
         }'

SELECT line.[key] as line_number, line.value
FROM OPENJSON(@polygon, '$.coordinates') line
```

Cuando ejecuto el código me salta el error de **Must declare the scalar variable "@polygon".**
Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal? Basicamente estoy aprendiendo y no estoy encontrando la respuesta a porque no se declara @polygon.
Mil gracias!

Comment: El código que compartiste no tiene ningún error.  ¿Estás ejecutándolo todo al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Sisi! Los estoy ejecutando todo al mismo tiempo pero me salta el error igual jajaja

Comment: Pues copiando el código y ejecutándolo en SQL Server 2017 o posterior no me marca ningún error. En 2016 marca un error distinto puesto que no existe la función `OPENJSON`